# Executable vs wrapper class

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, wkhtmltopdf

I am working on a project using asp.net and c# and I need to pull in something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org). I realize that there have been several good wrapper classes written to simplify calls to the dlls using c#. But is there a reason why I should not invoke the executable directly? Is there any performance or security gain from using a wrapper library?

Although, my specific need now is to use wkhtmltopdf, I have had the same question in the past when using libraries like [imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of preference.  By using the wrapper classes you mentioned, the work that you do implementing components that you may not be so familiar with is reduced, thereby freeing up your valuable time to concentrate on those aspects of the application where perhaps you can make your strongest value-add, such as the overall application architecture and design, or perhaps the application's business logic.

If you choose to write all the code yourself, then you may find that you're a less productive developer than your competition.

And, as @UweKeim points out in his comment, performance may be a factor as well.  If the wrapper code does not perform to your needs, you may well need to bypass it and go straight to the component/code library you're calling.

It's important to strike a balance between use of code that others have written, versus your own.  Important factors are things such as, how well is the 3rd party code written, how well is it supported, how well it performs, etc.  Choose wisely!

Comment: It could also be a matter of performance, I guess. Spawning a new process for each call inside a web application is much slower than having an in-process solution, IMHO.

Comment: @UweKeim, you make a very good point.  I will edit my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of `wkhtmltopdf` and using it inside an ASP.NET application is not recommended at all. All the wrappers serialize access to the conversion process (you cannot have two Qt event loops running inside the same process), so it makes sense to just call the executable directly using `System.Diagnostics.Process`.